# Copy a function in python

Tags: python, function, copy-paste

I created a function `collatz` that runs properly. Then based on a list of numbers that I set to be 512 numbers long, should run through the function that many times to add the number of iterations to get to with the loop:

```
for number in numbers: 
     collatz(number)
```

This worked as expected, except that it preempted the iteration within the function. This left me with a list of iterations all reading 0, though the list of numbers populated properly. For reference, the function which I want to copy is:

```
def collatz(n):
    iterations = []
    iterations.append(n)
    if n == 1 or n < 1:
        iterate_num = len(iterations) - 1
        all_iterations.append(iterate_num)
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        even = n / 2
        collatz(even)
    elif n % 2 != 0:
        odd = (3 * n) + 1
        collatz(odd)
    else:
        pass
```

Is it possible to copy that function a number of times equivalent to the length of the list of numbers to run through each separately?

Comment: "should run through the function that many times to add the number of iterations to get to with the loop" - huh?

Comment: What? Your function doesn't actually appear to return *anything*, so what are you expecting to get?!

Comment: remove global state (e.g.: pass it as a parameter).

Comment: `all_iterations.append(iterate_num)` is not in scope. You need to give more information.

Comment: in lines 2 and 3 you create and append 1 element to a list. If n is equal to 1 you append 0 to all_iterations (as the length of iterations is 1 at that point). Otherwise you recursively call the function again not using the "iterations" list at all. You might want to to change collatz to take a number and a list as an argument and write

    `for number in numbers:
        collatz(n, [])`

Comment: Your function isn't iterating, it is recursing, but you don't define any global state that is shared with deeper levels of the recursion.

Comment: What TheBlackCat said. You don't need recursion here, a simple loop would be much more efficient. Also, Python limits the depth of recursion, which would stop you investigating long Collatz sequences. OTOH, recursion with a cache of computed sequences _could_ be useful, but that might be a bit too advanced for your current Python skill level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `iterations` and extend it with the result of your recursive calls:

```
def collatz(n):
    # Stuff
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        even = n / 2
        iterations.extend(collatz(even))
    else:
        odd = (3 * n) + 1
        iterations.extend(collatz(odd))
    return iterations
```

Another solution would be to pass iterations by reference:

```
def collatz(n, iterations = None):
    if iterations is None:
        iterations = []
    # Stuff
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        even = n / 2
        collatz(even, iterations)
    else:
        odd = (3 * n) + 1
        collatz(odd, iterations)
```

Additionally, this construct is unnecessary:

```
elif n % 2 == 0:
    # stuff
elif n % 2 != 0:
    # stuff
else:
    pass
```

First off, having an `else:` than only does `pass` is unecessary in itself. Additionally, here `n % 2` can only either be zero or not zero so the else clause will never be reached.

Comment: `def collatz(n, iterations = [])` warning, using default parameters like this, `iterations` is _the same_ list each time you call the function!